# Collect threaddumps in weblogic server

Tags: linux, weblogic, thread-dump

i am trying to collect threaddumps in linux environment in my weblogic server using the following commands:

```
#jrcmd pid print_threads > outputfile.txt
kill -3 pid > outputfile.txt
jstack pid > outputfile.txt
```

But i am just getting an empty file. nothign is in the file genrated. Can any one please suggest how to get thread dumps in my weblogic server?

If we use kill -3 pid.. where will the threaddumps saved?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

`kill -3 <pid>` is the standard way. For your last question, if you are running your application in tomcat, thread dump will be sent in to /logs/catalina.out file.

Comment: my application is running in weblogic. Any idea where will it be saved in weblogic?

Comment: It should be located in `DOMAIN_NAME/servers/SERVER_NAME/logs` directory. `SERVER_NAME.out` should be the file name

Comment: If you want to a custom file for it, edit the WebLogic Server script so that the JAVA_OPTIONS variable specifies the following:

`-Dweblogic.Stdout="stdout-filename"
-Dweblogic.Stderr="stderr-filename"`